# How to add an existing workflow to a list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I've a workflow in SharePoint 2010 and I'd like use this one on an existing document library.

When I go to Library settings and Workflow settings, I don't see my workflow.

If I go to SharePoint Designer, I see the workflow list but I can't attach it to my library.

Finally i did a new workflow on my list, it was faster

Comment: Is it a list workflow? Is it published?

Comment: yes it's a list workflow and it's published if i check in SPD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List Workflow are Associated with one particular List while Reusable Workflow Associate to Content Type.so it is reusable.you can attach it to any list or library. So if you want to attach workflow with another library create a reusable workflow.

Below is the url where you can get more detail:

http://devendra-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/02/list-workflow-vs-reusable-wokflow-vs.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have an orphaned List Workflow that you wanted to associate to another list, it becomes tricky because the list must have the workflow built with that association from the start.  You can do this, however:

1. In SharePoint Designer, go to Workflows and select the workflow you want.  From the ribbon, select Export to Visio, and save the workflow with a .vwi extension – add “-Source” to the title.
2. In the ribbon, select the Workflow tab > List Workflows, then select the list you want to associate your workflow with.
3. In the next dialog, give it the name you want (something other than the existing name), select SharePoint 2010 Workflow, and select OK.
4. Upon creation, click Save and Publish the empty workflow.
5. Select the Export to Visio option and save the workflow with a .vwi extension – add “-Destination” to the title.  Close the tab.
6. Add the .zip extension to both the files and open both.  Copy workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml from destination workflow to source workflow. (It is **destination to source**, not source to destination).
7. Remove the .zip extension from the Source Workflow .vwi.zip file to reset it back to a .vwi file, and delete the “–Destination” file.  It will no longer be needed.  We will be importing this updated source workflow.
8. Open Workflows in the sidebar in SPD, but select the new, blank workflow (just select - don't open).  Click Import from Visio and select Import Visio 2010 Diagram.  Browse to the Source Workflow .vwi file and select Next.
9. Select Finish on the next screen.  The workflow will be imported.

You can use this method to transfer workflows from site to site, as well, such as when you have a development, test, and production version of the same site.  If you do this in such a manner, there, though, list lookups tend to need re-mapping since List GUIDs tend to be unique - even on copies of the sites.

Answer (score 1):

To link an existing **List Workflow** to the new **list**, I have used an approach described [here](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/applying-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-multiple-lists/) and it worked for me (SharePoint 2013 on-premises).

**My situation:**

1. I had to copy existing subsite with **List Workflow** to other
   SharePoint farm.
2. After **Export-Import PowerShell command** execution List Workflow lost
   list assotiation (on destination farm).

**Solution:**

1. Create a new workflow (Workflow 2010 with SPD 2013) on the list.
2. Create at least one step, one condition and one action in this
   workflow. This ensures that will be created necessary workflow files
   (.xoml and so on).
3. From the original workflow open the **.xoml** file as XML and copy the
   entire contents to the clipboard.
4. Open the **.xoml** file for the new workflow and replace the entire
   contents with the copy from (3).
5. Repeat this operation for the **xoml.rules** file.
6. (This step was needed in my case) Restart SPD, otherwise SPD don't
   show workflow changes, while executing (7).
7. Double click the .xoml file for the new workflow to open the
   workflow in the **Workflow Designer** and click **Check Workflow** to verify
   no errors and then click Finish to ensure the workflow is saved.